# polars - processing of 7 GB parquet aborts with segmentation fault

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a 7 GB `.parquet` file with a 128M rows of accounting data (which I cannot share) and split in to 53 row groups.  My task is to 'clean' the data by retaining in each cell, only specific words from a dictionary.  The reading of the file is trouble free.  The processing of the file ends in a segmentation fault on a 20-core, 128GB RAM Ubuntu O/S desktop.

Using Python and the Polars library, I convert the data in to a Polars data frame with the following columns:

```
['rowid', 'txid', 'debit', 'credit', 'effective_date', 'entered_date', 'user_id', 'transaction', 'memo', 'type', 'account', 'total_amt']
```

The columns to be cleaned in this file are `memo`, `type`, and `account`.  My approach is to take each of those columns and apply a `filter_field` method to them and the problem occurs in the loop I made to do that:

```
        # two-step cleaning: first memo/account fields
        for memo_field in memo_columns+account_columns:
            print('memo_field:', memo_field)
            data = data.with_columns(
                (pl.col(memo_field).map_elements(lambda x: self.filter_field(text=x, word_dict=word_dict))).alias('clean_' + memo_field) # baseline
                )
            data = data.drop(memo_field)  #drop cleaned column
```

In each loop, I'm actually creating a new "clean" column and then dropping the original.

I know the filtering is sound b/c everything runs fine on near identical files of up to 78M rows.  When I run this larger file I see the memory consumption climb steadily until the seg fault.  Just before the seg fault I noticed in `htop` that about a dozen processes seemingly identical to the main python process are spawned but it happened too fast for me to see what exactly happened there.

What I would like to know:

1. is there a better approach than the looping/mapping I'm using;
2. are there improvements I could make for memory management; or
3. is this simply a case of needing more resources

Update:

Changed the code so that instead of creating a new column and dropping the old, I just change the column (like Pandas 'inplace'?).  This allowed processing of the entire file.  Each column takes ~1500 sec to be cleaned.

HOWEVER, a write error now appears:  `Parquet cannot store strings with size 2GB or more`.  This does not make sense to me as the data can only shrink in size through the cleaning process.

Comment: When a Python program uses multiprocessing, each subprocess may duplicate some amount of memory from the parent process (depending on the method of multiprocessing and data handling). So, you'll have to make sure that nothing is configured to use more threads/processes than you expect. Also, you can look into batching rather than doing it all in one shot. Lastly, even though this isn't my area of expertise, it seems like Dask is designed to do something similar, but without running into RAM issues. All worth looking into.

Comment: Can you share the code for `def filter_field`? `.map_elements` is a "last resort" - you should be able to achieve what you want using Polars expressions. i.e. if you want to just delete certain strings you can [`.str.replace_many`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.replace_many.html#polars.Expr.str.replace_many) them with the empty string. There's also `.str.replace_all` if you need to use regex.

Comment: @RandomDavis I've included htop snip.  Note the seemingly identical subprocesses even though I haven't intentionally applied any parallelism.  Does Polars spawn subprocesses?  Memory use climbs steadily until the seg fault.  I am looking in to Dask.

Comment: Polars could spawn subprocesses if you have it configured to use more than one thread; not sure on this, but worth checking all the settings.

Comment: @jqurious each cell gets broken up in to 'words' which incl. alphanumeric string. 
 Each word is then processed.  It's a cleaning designed to retain as much information as possible.  Might not be worth it in the end but I'm testing an idea.

Comment: How are you reading in the DataFrame? Is it eager or lazy?

Comment: @BallpointBen I am using default values for `.read_parquet` reading the largest files.

Comment: `read_parquet` is eager. What happens if you switch to `scan_parquet`?

Comment: @BallpointBen  Just to clarify:  reading seems to be okay.  The process reads in a large file and a v. small file, and does a join to produce the df that gets cleaned.  If I change how the files are read, will that affect the join or processing?

Comment: `.map_elements` is basically doing `for row in df[column]: func(row)` i.e. each row is processed sequentially at the "Python level". You should instead implement the logic using [Expressions](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/string.html#string) which run at the "Rust level" (and can be parallelized).

Comment: @RandomDavis how do I check Polars settings?